# How to use EntityRuler and label my entity correctly

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

How it should work

- "my doaq is ABCDAE" - because ABCDAE is six characters and we have doaq in the sentence, it should label ABCDAE a CODE
- "my account code which is A7C6A9" - because A7C6A9 is six characters and we have account code in the sentence, it should label A7C6A9 a CODE
- "I like my dog with 7861A3" - because 7861A3 is a six characters and we don't have "account code" and "doaq" in the sentence, it shouldn't label 7861A3 as a CODE

"""

My code

```
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()

# Initialize EntityRuler
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")

# Define patterns for the EntityRuler
patterns = [
    {"label": "CODE", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "doaq"}, {"SHAPE": "xxxxxx"}]},
    {"label": "CODE", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "account"}, {"LOWER": "code"}, {"SHAPE": "xxxxxx"}]},
]

# Add patterns to the EntityRuler
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)


# Example text
texts = [
    "my doaq is ABCDAE",
    "my account code which is A7C6A9",
    "I like my dog with 7861A3"
]

# Process each text
for text in texts:
    doc = nlp(text)

    # Extract entities
    entities = [(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents]
    print(f"Text: {text}, Extracted Entities: {entities}")
```

Current result

```
Text: my doaq is ABCDAE, Extracted Entities: []
Text: my account code which is A7C6A9, Extracted Entities: []
Text: I like my dog with 7861A3, Extracted Entities: []
```

Expected Result

```
Text: my doaq is ABCDAE, Extracted Entities: [('ABCDAE', 'CODE')]
Text: my account code which is A7C6A9, Extracted Entities: [('A7C6A9', 'CODE')]
Text: I like my dog with 7861A3, Extracted Entities: []
```

How do I fix my code?